# Detailed shipping method information from order in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a website where i need to get shipping carrier name ( e.g. USPS ) , carrier description ( First-Class Mail® (USPS) ) and carrier code ( e.g. USS 04 ). Now i can see this information in the order details page but how i can get this information on plugin ? WC_order or WC_shipping has no function to get this. I searched through mysql and it seems two tables store this information wp_postmeta and wp_woocommerce_order_items

Do i have to get this from sql ?

Answer (score 1):

if you have the WC_Order in $order, you can access the shipping method name by:

```
$order->get_shipping_method()
```

Comment: it was actually more than knowing shipping method name. Turns out, it was in WC_ORDER array. Anyway thanks for digging some time for me :)

Comment: ok, if this answered your question please mark the answered checkbox.